# How to find number of conflicts in a table?

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets, filter, array-formulas

I'm working on a table where a list of courses and students all are listed and trying to find out which courses can put on the same time-slot without having any conflicts **(to prevent having more than one exam at the same time)** either in Google Sheets or Microsoft Excel.

#### Below is a simple example of the main table

```
StudentID Course Name
1          Math
1          English
1          Computer
2          English
2          Computer 
3          Physics
```

and I want something similar to below

```
           English    Computer    Physics
Math        No           No         Yes
English     -            No         Yes
Computer    No           -          Yes
Physics     -            Yes        -
```

Simply, I want to know which courses can put together in the same time-slot without conflicts.

Comment: Can you add a sample of what the classes' time slots look like?  What have you tried already?

Comment: Could you please be more specific! Actually we are using another software to design the schedule with, but a little bit preparation is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in cell **D2**:

```
=UNIQUE(B2:B)
```

[image: 0]

paste in cell **E1**:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B3:B))
```

[image: 0]

paste in cell **E2** and drag down then drag to the right:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E$1=$D2, "-", 
 IF(SUM(N(REGEXMATCH(FILTER($A$2:$A, $B$2:$B=E$1)&"", 
 "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, FILTER($A$2:$A, $B$2:$B=$D2))&"$")))=0, "yes", "no")))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

**Google Sheets**

The condition should be that the count of unique student id's is the same as the count of student ID's for the two subjects:

```
=if(E$1=$D2,"-",if(count(filter($A2:$A,regexmatch($B2:$B,E$1&"|"&$D2)))=countunique(filter($A2:$A,regexmatch($B2:$B,E$1&"|"&$D2))),"Yes","No"))
```

[image]

You can do it a little shorter just with a grouping query to test if any student has more than one of the two courses:

```
=if(E$1=$D2,"-",if(max(query($A2:$B,"select count(A) where B='"&E$1&"' or B='"&$D2&"' group by A"))=1,"Yes","No"))
```

**Excel**

This requires a bit more effort - you'd probably use Frequency to get the same effect as grouping in Google sheets. The logic is the same though:

```
=IF(E$1=$D2,"-",IF(MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(($B$2:$B$7=E$1)+($B$2:$B$7=$D2),$A$2:$A$7),$A$2:$A$7))=1,"Yes","No"))
```

This assumes that the ID's are numeric. Has to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]